# Creating rotation matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, rotation, linear-algebra

I need to create a rotation function that will be used to rotate items around, it nearly works apart from when trying to do -sin.
There doesnt seem to be a function that allows this.

[image: Rotation matrix]

```
Matrix.createRotation = function (rotation) {

    return new Matrix(Math.cos(rotation),  Math.sin(rotation), 0,
        Math.sin(rotation), Math.cos(rotation), 0, 0, 0, 1);
};
```

Comment: What about something like `(-1) * Math.sin(rotation)`? Shouldn't that work? As in the function should be like this, `return new Matrix(Math.cos(rotation),  (-1) * Math.sin(rotation), 0, Math.sin(rotation), Math.cos(rotation), 0, 0, 0, 1);`

Comment: Yeah you're right it does work.

Comment: In your example you don't even negate the result of `Math.sin(rotation)`. It should be `-Math.sin(rotation)` - it is faster than multiplying by `-1`. How do you expect `-sin(rotation)` if you don't negate the result of `sin(rotation)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to negate the result of `Math.sin(rotation)` as `-Math.sin(rotation)`:

```
Matrix.createRotation = function (rotation)
{ 
    return new Matrix(
        Math.cos(rotation), -Math.sin(rotation), 0,
        Math.sin(rotation), Math.cos(rotation), 0,
        0, 0, 1
    );
};
```

Note that `-Math.sin(rotation)` is faster than `(-1)*Math.sin(rotation)`.